# list index out of range, global variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
def queens(i):
    n=8

    if (promising(i)):
        if(i==n):
            for col in range(1,n):
                print(col)
        else:
            for j in range (1,n):
                    col[i+1]=j
                    i=i+1
def promising(i):

    k=1
    switch=True
    while(k<i and switch):

        if(col[i]==col[k] and abs(col[i]-col[k]==i-k)):
                switch= False
        else:
            switch=True
    k+=1
    return switch
```

I wish to run n-queens problem using back-tracking. I don't know how to rectify the error regarding col variable, i think we need some global variable.

Can anyone explain how to use global variables and why we get list index out of bound error.

Comment: i had added the code as u edited, it automatically got save in that weird format!

Comment: How are you calling these?

Comment: by first calling promising(i), giving some value to i like 4 or 8. and then calling queens(4) or queens(8)

Comment: can u rectify the code ?please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be the reason that you are working with `range(1,n)` but python is zero indexed?

And that you add +1 to your variable i, but this is the column vector, so if you are at `i = n`, `i+1` is out of bounds?

I thinks this is whats wrong in your first function.

Comment: consider accepting the answer and closing the thread if your problem is solved. thanks :)